# Enabling NCSA access log with wsadmin scrpting

Tags: console, websphere, jython, wsadmin

How can someone enable NCSA access log by using wsadmin script.

To view the settings page for an HTTP channels in WAS console we follow these steps:
Servers > Server Types > WebSphere application servers > server > Web Container Settings > Web container transport chains > Chain > HTTP inbound channel.

On the console, there is no administrative assistance for this task!!
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below snippet. I have added comments for each step.

Update the first two lines - serverName and chainName as per your environment before running this.

```
serverName = 'server1'
chainName = 'Chain'

#update this variable to true/false to toggle logging on/off
loggingEnabled = 'true'

#Get the server id
serverId = AdminConfig.getid('/Server:%s' %(serverName))

#Get the list of all Web Container transport chains
wcTransportChains = AdminTask.listChains(AdminConfig.list("TransportChannelService", serverId), '[-acceptorFilter WebContainerInboundChannel]').splitlines()

#Iterate the list and find the chain we are interested in 
for chain in wcTransportChains:
    if chain.startswith(chainName):
        #list all transport channles for this chain
        transportChannels = AdminConfig.showAttribute(chain, 'transportChannels').split(" ")
        #iterate the list and find HTTPInboundChannel to enable NCSA logging
        for channel in transportChannels:
            if channel.find('HTTPInboundChannel') != -1:
                #Enable logging config
                print ('\nEnabling NCSA logging for Transport Channel : %s on server : %s\n' %(AdminConfig.showAttribute(channel, 'name'), serverName))
                AdminConfig.modify(channel, [['enableLogging', loggingEnabled]])
            #end if
        #end for
    #end if
#end for

#save the changes
AdminConfig.save()
```

Comment: Thanks. Will give it a try and let you know